# Open Thickening of Closed Balls - Homotopy Equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let us assume we have a finite union of closed ball with radius $\alpha$ around points $x$ in a Euclidean space
$$M:= \bigcup_{i \in \{1,...,q\}}B_\alpha(x_i)$$
Can I "thicken" them to open balls $B^\circ_{\alpha +\epsilon}(x_i)$ such that
$$M \text{   is homotopy equivalent to   } \bigcup_{i \in \{1,...,q\}}B^\circ_{\alpha+ \epsilon}(x_i)$$
It should work, but could you tell me the reason why? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}$. Let $x_1=+1$, $x_2=-1$ and take $\alpha=1$. Then $B_1(-1)\cup B_1(1)\simeq \{+1,-1\}$ is up to homotopy a discrete two point space, while $B_{1+\epsilon}(-1)\cup B_{1+\epsilon}(-1)$ is contractible for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks @Tyrone for your answer. But I wanted the balls to be closed balls, so in your example $B_1(-1) \cup B_1(1) \cong [-1, 1]$ and thererfore contractible too.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the closed bit.